# How do you prove that $\operatorname{row}(\mathbf{AB})$ is contained in $\operatorname{ row}(\mathbf B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this an okay way to prove this?

Say a is in $\operatorname{row}(\mathbf{AB})$ and there exists a $y$ such that $a = (\mathbf{AB})y$.
Then $a = \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A}y)$
Since $a$ is in the row space of $\mathbf B$ then a system of linear equations $\mathbf By=a$ has solutions.
So, $\operatorname{row} (\mathbf{AB})$ is contained in $\operatorname{row}(\mathbf B)$

Also, does anyone know what theorem allows you to go from that last step to saying that then $\operatorname{rank} (\mathbf{AB}) \leq \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf B)$

Comment: If $a=(AB)y$ it is not true that $a=B(Ay)$.

Comment: Why do you think this is true? It is not.

Comment: Why not? Isn't that just the associative property of multiplication

Comment: No, that is not associativity, unless you are using very bad notion. In most notation, $(AB)y=A(By)$. You can't switch the orders.

Comment: I was trying to use the way I proved col(AB) is contained in col(A). In that problem I said that b = (AB)x and then b = A(Bx). So, I thought for this problem you could also do b = B(Ax)

Comment: Row in that sense is the left action - $a\in \mathrm{row}(A)$ if and only if $a=yA$ for some $y$. Then the same approach works.

Answer (score 0):

Using what you've already shown, $$row(AB)=col((AB)^T)=col(B^{T}A^{T})\subseteq col(B^T)=row(B)$$

Then $$rank(AB)=\dim(row(AB))\le\dim(row(B))=rank(B)$$